# Convert Hex String Color to uint_16

Tags: arduino

I need to convert a HEX string to uint_16 in order to use a [fillColor method](https://docs.m5stack.com/#/en/api/lcd?id=fillscreen) for the m5Stack hardware.

I'm currently fetching the HEX color value via a GET request to https://m5stack.glitch.me/getColor

I tried
`uint16_t color = (uint16_t) strtol(http.getString(), NULL, 16);`

But am getting the error
`cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long int strtol(const char*, char**, int)'`

How can I take a string HEX color value and convert it to uint_16?

Answer (score 4):

The `strtol()` can't handle a String Object as input. You must convert it into a character array.

```
strtol(http.getString().c_str(), NULL, 16);
```